# How to divide only a certain factor in a column in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, division

This is the sample dataset:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(x = c(1000,2000,10,2), y = c('A','A','B','B'))
```

I only want to divide `df$y == "A" by 1000`. The final dataset should appear as:

```
df = data.table(x = c(1,2,10,2), y = c('A','A','B','B'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a conditional statement.

In base R:

```r
df$x <- ifelse(df$y == "A", df$x/1000, df$x)
```

In `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- df |>
    mutate(x = if_else(y == "A", x/1000, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` option using `fifelse` like this:

```r
library(data.table)
df = data.table(x = c(1000,2000,10,2), y = c('A','A','B','B'))
df[,x:=fifelse(y == "A", x/1000, x),]
df
#>     x y
#> 1:  1 A
#> 2:  2 A
#> 3: 10 B
#> 4:  2 B
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We could use `data.table` methods as the input is a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df[y == 'A', x := x/1000]
```

-output

```
> df
    x y
1:  1 A
2:  2 A
3: 10 B
4:  2 B
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R: Subsetting with `[`:

```
df$x[df$y == "A"] <- df$x[df$y == "A"]/1000
```

```
    x y
1:  1 A
2:  2 A
3: 10 B
4:  2 B
```